# Controlling initial state of a destination StackNavigator from initial SwitchNavigator screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a `SwitchNavigator` 'switch'. It's initial state 'root' is a screen component that is just loading state and determining the correct initial route (A, or B) of a `StackNavigator` 'stack'.

```
--switch
     --root
     --stack
        -A
        -B
```

what's the right way for the 'root' component to tell the Switch Navigator to switch to 'stack' and then start with either 'A or B' conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working simply by running my navigation request through a reset action on 'stack'.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key:'stack',
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'B' })
    ]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

In the root component, when your job is done, just call `navigation.navigate` like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(condition ? 'A' : 'B');
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work for me is that even when I choose condition B, I still end up with screen B pushed on top of screen A.